# Permission denied for .iPython after installing django-CMS

Tags: django, linux, ipython, django-cms, ubuntu-server

Using the most recent package of [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) - it requires a package called [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb).
I installed it and now I cannot get past the error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.ipython'
```

I changed the permission of the folder and it didn't work.

I also created the file manually - but then the error is:

```
[Errno 17] File exists: '/var/www/.ipython'
```

My google-foo has faulted to resolve this.

---

The permissions on this folder I changed to the current user used to login. Is there a particular user I can apply to this folder of which I don't know about?

---

## Fixed!

After the advice I had a further poke around to get it working:

1. chmod 777 on the parent folder of which will contain the .ipython file
2. chmod 777 on the .ipython once created
3. chmod 755 onto parent folder again.

Works!

It seems this file must be executable - of course I don't want that on my main folder, so I can allow it to be created and then revert my changes.

Thanks you both for your advice

Comment: What are the current permissions and owner of that folder?

Comment: The permission are 775 - the owner is me - the login I use to log into the terminal

Comment: you better not set 777 on /var/www. why should other have rwx-rights on it?

Comment: @naeg - Hence: "3. chmod 755 onto parent folder again."

Comment: django CMS does not require ipdb. Could you tell me where this is used in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user with which you are trying to access /var/www isn't allowed to do so. You either use a different user or you change the permissions of /var/www.

This is btw not a python question, it's a linux question.

With `ls -l /var/www` you can see who is allowed to create new files inside the directory.

A little guide that shall explain to you how permissions work in linux: http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Security/Quick_and_Dirty_Guide_to_Linux_File_Permissions